# Aligning social media buttons horizontally on Tumblr

Tags: html, css, button, facebook-like, tumblr

I successfully added the like and tweet buttons to my blog, but I'm not sure how to horizontally align them after each post. What i'm trying to do is put the tweet button just left of the facebook like button so it's nice and neat. Eventually I would like to add the G+ button, too.

My blog is www.thoughtsrandom.com

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the code. I placed after {/block:PostNotes}

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>

<script>(function(d){

var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}

js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;

js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=236186013100076&xfbml=1";

d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);

}(document));</script>

<div class="fb-like" data-href="{permalink}" data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-  faces="true"></div>

<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-via="nhuntzinger">Tweet</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id))    {js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

Comment: you can do it very easily by changing the width and position of the elements. let me add G+ button for demo.

Answer (score 0):

Check the below fiddle and set the elements as per your need, you can easily accomplish this without any hassle.

Fiddle :http://jsfiddle.net/pVaLL/1/

Demo :  http://jsfiddle.net/pVaLL/1/embedded/result/

Comment: Thank you for your response. The alignment is right; however, the buttons themselves are no longer functional. Also, when I like one button, the rest of my posts are liked as well.

Comment: I just copy your code from your above mention website to show you demonstration, I didnt have the real code thats why i showed you demo in fiddle so you can see and develop as per your need.

Comment: Thank you. As you can tell, I am new to this.